# Hibernate: returning null when getting the object in a one to one relation

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

Whenever I try to get the joined object it is returning null. Sample code below:

## Table A

```
id
name
b_id
```

## Table B

```
id
name
```

## Coding

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false)
    private B b;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public B getb() {        
        return b;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getname() {        
        return name;
    }
}
```

When I use `getA(id).getB()` function it returns null. When I use `getA` it returns a valid object and not null.

Comment: it would be nice to know the tables structures for a better help

Comment: @EduardoMeneses i already gave the table structure above. are you probably asking for another thing?

Comment: @antman did you ever get it to work? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your @Id and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
and placed above your id variable like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")

public class A{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false)
private B b;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public B getb() {

    return b;
}
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: These annotations work just as well on top of the respective getter

Comment: didnt work the result still is null when i do getB()

Answer (score 0):

May be you should give the FetchType as Eager in the joinColumn annotation to get object B also loaded while a is loaded.

Comment: i think fecth method can only be used in the `@onetoone it gives a error when using in the join. anyway i tried in the onetoone and it still didnt work still null result

Answer (score 0):

You could consider use more annotation properties, for example:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColum(name = "b_id" referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private B b;
```

Comment: still returned null

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")

public class B{
**@Column(name="b_id", nullable=false)**
private Integer id;
private String name;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getname() {

    return name;
}
}
```

Use @Column(name="b_id", nullable=false)

Comment: still returns null same as before